# could I use django-image-cropping (ImageCroppingMixin) also with Django Admin TabularInline view?

Tags: django, admin, inline

I have a working ImageCroppingMixin view in Djano Admin
So I can ajust the crop areas and save the image and its crop settings.

But I would also want to be able to edit the picture this way when I'm viewing the "Referentie" as a whole (with all pictures shown as a admin.TabularInline view)

I keep getting the plain text fields in the TabularInline view of the corresponding pictures.

My admin.py code:

```
class ReferentieFotoAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('foto', 'referentie', 'volgnummer', 'op_frontpage', )
    ordering =("-volgnummer",)


class ReferentieFotoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ReferentieFoto


class ReferentieDetailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ReferentieDetail

class ReferentieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
               ReferentieDetailInline, 
               ReferentieFotoInline,
               ]
    ordering = ("volgnummer",)
    list_filter = ['datum', 'volgnummer']


class TipAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ("volgnummer",)

class SiteInfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False


class KlantAdminSite(AdminSite):
    klantInfo = SiteInfo.objects.get(id=1)
    site_header = "Websitebeheer voor: " + klantInfo.website_naam + " | " + klantInfo.bedrijfsslogan
    index_title = "Sitebeheer - Home" 


adminCappaert = KlantAdminSite('CappaertAdmin')


django.contrib.admin.site = adminCappaert

autodiscover()

adminCappaert.register(Referentie, ReferentieAdmin)
adminCappaert.register(ReferentieFoto, ReferentieFotoAdmin)
adminCappaert.register(SiteInfo, SiteInfoAdmin)
adminCappaert.register(DeKlantSpreekt)
adminCappaert.register(Tip, TipAdmin)
adminCappaert.register(ContactBericht)
```

---

models.py

---

```
class ReferentieFoto(models.Model):
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='referenties', blank=True, null=True)
    cropping_referenties = ImageRatioField('foto', "866x461", size_warning=True)
    referentie = models.ForeignKey(Referentie)
    volgnummer = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    op_frontpage = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    cropping_frontpage = ImageRatioField('foto', "1920x656", size_warning=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Referentiefoto"
        verbose_name_plural = "Referentiefoto's"
class Referentie(models.Model):
    titel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    beschrijving = models.TextField()
    datum = models.DateField()
    volgnummer = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titel + ' - ' +str(self.datum)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Referentie"
        verbose_name_plural = "Referenties"
```

Any ideas how I could do the same with Inline class views?

Thanks already!

Comment: SOLUTION:class ReferentieDetailInline(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    model = ReferentieDetail

Answer (score 0):

In your admin.py

```
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = ImageModel
        extra = 0

        def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
            crop_fields = getattr(self.model, 'crop_fields', {})
            if db_field.name in crop_fields:
                kwargs['widget'] = image_cropping.ImageCropWidget

            return super(ImageInline, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```

This solution works fine with Django 1.8.x